# Combine date and time column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Good morning,

I have a question regarding combining date and time columns into a single column in pandas.

**The data types of my columns are as follows:**

Date column:  `ytdsorted["Checkin\nDate"].dtype` 
output: dtype('<M8[ns]')

Time column: `ytdsorted["Checkin\nTime"].dtype`
output: dtype('O')

**A preview of how my data looks is as follows:**

Date column: `ytdsorted["Checkin\nDate"].head(1)`
output: 2021-10-01

Time column: `ytdsorted["Checkin\nTime"].head(1)`
output: 12:42 PM

**I would like to combine the date and time column to give me a 24hr format:  "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"**

Any help would be much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date":["2021-10-01"],
    "Time":["12:42 PM"]
})
df["dateMerge"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]+" "+df["Time"], infer_datetime_format=True)

Date            Time             dateMerge
2021-10-01      12:42 PM         2021-10-01 12:42:00
```